# Map collection using foreign key with constant value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.0

I have designed table that can contains parameters (*Parameters*) for records from multiple tables (*Students*, *Teachers*).

As a foreign key on a parameters table i'm using an enum (*Student*, *Teacher*) paired by column with primary key from multiple tables.

How can i fill object collection (*Student.Parameters*, *Teacher.Parameters*) with records from Parameters table?

I will try to explain on simple example of school.

EF Core Code First DB Context:

```
class Student
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public IList<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; } 
}
class Teacher
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public IList<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; } 
}
enum EntityType
{
   Student,
   Teacher
}
class Parameter
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public EntityType EntityType { get; set; }
   public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
class SchoolDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Parameter>()
          .HasKey(prm => new { prm.EntityType, prm.EntityId });
   }
}
```

To fill *Parameters* collection of *Teacher* object (and Student.Parameters too), i expect application to execute SQL like:

```
SELECT prm.*
  FROM Teachers tch
  LEFT JOIN Parameters prm
    ON prm.EntityType = 'Teacher'
   AND prm.EntityId = tch.Id
 WHERE tch.Id = @id
```

To use it like this (for cascade delete too, if it's possible):

```
Guid studentId = .....;
var student = SchoolDbContext.Students
   .Include(s => s.Parameters)
   .Find(studentId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you do it like this and use a table per hierarchy strategy? https://entityframework.net/tph

```
enum EntityType
{
   Student,
   Teacher
}
class Person
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public EntityType EntityType { get; set; }
    public IList<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; } 
}
class Student : Person
{

}
class Teacher : Person
{

}
class Parameter
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting and should definitely work in cases of when class is inherited from base class. Also there be no point of using entity type enum (i think two tables will share same primary key sequence). But when entities have no same base class, this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need and a similar scheme as the original poster. I was able to get it to work with a TPH strategy as mentioned above. Then I had a business requirement that this relationship was to be editable, and EF Core will not let you edit the property that is the discriminator. The best solution I found was to create a computed column on the related entities that stored the EntityType (always returning the value that related to that EntityType) Not the best, but what is working so far. I tried using a fixed value for the EntityType of HasPrinicipalKey, but received an error that EF Core does not allow it.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceNote>()
            .HasOne(sn => sn.Policy)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(sn => new { sn.EntityId, sn.EntityType })
            .HasPrincipalKey(policy => new { EntityId = policy.Id, EntityType = policy.ServiceNoteEntityType });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceNote>()
            .HasOne(sn => sn.Quote)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(sn => new { sn.EntityId, sn.EntityType })
            .HasPrincipalKey(quote => new { EntityId = quote.Id, EntityType = quote.ServiceNoteEntityType });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceNote>()
            .HasOne(sn => sn.Agency)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(sn => new { sn.EntityId, sn.EntityType })
            .HasPrincipalKey(agency => new { EntityId = agency.Id, EntityType = agency.ServiceNoteEntityType });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ServiceNote>()
            .HasOne(sn => sn.Client)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(sn => new { sn.EntityId, sn.EntityType })
            .HasPrincipalKey(client => new { EntityId = client.Id, EntityType = client.ServiceNoteEntityType });
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use like this

```
class Student
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   // add virtual
   public virtual IList<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; } 
}
class Teacher
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   // add virtual
   public virtual IList<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; } 
}
enum EntityType
{
   Student,
   Teacher
}
class Parameter
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public EntityType EntityType { get; set; }
   public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("Student")]
   public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("Teacher")]
   public Guid TeacherId { get; set; }
}
```

hope this helps you

Comment: This will create columns for student and teacher in database. By design there should be only two columns for binding. I have more than 2 tables that referred to Parameters table and i don't want to create %tablename%Id for every table.

Comment: @Rincew1nd "i don't want to create %tablename%Id for every table." - But you really should, otherwise there's no way to maintain the referential integrity of the database if  you don't want TPH and the same base class for all "parameter-ables". Also note that `EntityType` and `EntityId` in this answer are completely superfluous and should be removed, but otherwise this solution is the best one if TPH is not an option.